# Cannot view mp4 video on Apache2.4 website

Tags: apache2.4

I have added an .htaccess file in document root for the specific website on the server in /var/www/website/.htaccess

```
AddType video/mp4   .mp4
```

But there is no AllowOverRide directive in the 000-default.conf file to make the change.

I added the following to my apache2.conf file

```
<Directory /var/www/mywebsite/>
    Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

And restarted apache2 but still does not work.